# JavaScript functions and buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner at JavaScript. I have been trying to change HTML content with the following two functions that are supposed to be triggered by a button click:

```
<body>

  <p id="demo">This is a demonstration.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo2">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Click me!</button>


  <script>
  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
  }

  function myFunction2(){
      document.getElementByID("demo2").style.fontSize="25px";
      document.getElementByID("demo2").style.color="red";
      document.getElementByID("demo2").style.background-color="yellow";
  }
  </script>

</body>
```

For some reason I don't understand both of the functions don't work at the same time, but only separately.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what means on the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "functions don't work at the same time"?

Comment: yes, I want them to do different things.

Comment: I mean that if I delete the code for the second function for example, the first one works. But if they are both present, they dont.

Comment: Because of a syntax error in the 2nd function.  Note that ID is uppercase in all 3 lines of code.  Change that so it's the same as the 1st function.

Comment: @Archer Well spotted, if OP only would have said I get an error in my console or directly said button 2 doesn't trigger. Talking about worst way to explain something.

Comment: @Nope OP is a beginner.  They're learning how to ask as well as how to code :)

Comment: I understand @Archer I'm just being direct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `myFunction2`

```
getElementById
             ^ small letter
```

and

```
document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ a single property with capital
                                                       letter instead of dash
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.fontSize = "25px";
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This is a demonstration.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo2">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 errors in your code

1. In `myFunction2`, you mispelled `getElementByID` => it's `getElementById`.
2. In `myFunction2`, you mispelled `background-color` => it's `backgroundColor`.

"Hyphens" are not allowed in the names of properties or functions.

When corrected, your code works well. Here is the snippet.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
}

function myFunction2(){
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.fontSize="25px";
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.color="red";
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p id="demo">This is a demonstration.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

  <p id="demo2">JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Click me!</button>

</body>
```